# Polish letters from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, file-io, unicode-string, jtextcomponent

How to get `String` from `JTextField` or `JTextArea` with Polish letters?
when I use `myTxtArea.getText()` and in my `JTextArea` I've got `ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż` it only recognizes `?????Ó????????ó???`.

Text from both `JTextField` and `JTextArea` is going to be saved in *.txt file

That's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyAppCreateAcc {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AppGUI ag = new AppGUI();
    }
public MyAppCreateAcc() throws IOException {

    String group = AppGUI.getGroup().getText();

    String[] lines = AppGUI.getNote().getText().split("\\n");

    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            "zaloz_konta.cmd"));
    w.write("mode con codepage select=1250");
    w.newLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {

        /*
         * delete more than one space between words and from the full name
         * create a short one first letter of name and surname after all
         * lowercase like on example: John Smith = jsmith
         */
        if (lines[j] == null || lines[j].equals("")) {

            // if there is a gap between the names do nothing

        } else {
            lines[j] = lines[j].trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s([A-Za-z]+)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines[j]);
            String shortName = "";
            if (matcher.find()) {
                shortName = (lines[j].charAt(0) + matcher.group(1))
                        .toLowerCase();
            }

            w.write("call konto.cmd " + shortName + " \"" + lines[j]
                    + "\" 123 " + "\"" + group + "\"");
            w.newLine();
        }
    }
    w.close();
}

}
```

I want to get Polish letters just from:

`String[] lines = AppGUI.getNote().getText().split("\\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for [JTextCompoents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to use

- [JTextComponent.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) for output to FileIO
- [JTextComponent.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) for loading data from FileIO

by default accepting separators and Files encode page

Comment: how should I use it in my case?

Comment: [for example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextComponentwriteWriterout.htm), are you still an issue with encode page after using read() / write ()

Comment: isn't it that's what I am using?

Comment: not isn't, I can't see there JTextArea.write(), some constructor not in SSCCE form, notice and to use getDocument instead of getText, then you recaive formatted and stylled Document

Answer (score 2):

You want to use **UTF-8** Encoding. Give that a try

```
 String s = new String(AppGUI.getNote().getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
 String[] lines = s.split("\\n");
```

Comment: how about if my `String s` is an array?

Comment: `String[] lines = AppGUI.getNote().getText().split("\\n");`

Answer (score 1):

I extended my `pattern` and it helped as well:

```
lines[j] = lines[j].trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s([A-Za-ząćęłńóśźżĄĘŁĆŃÓŚŹŻ]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines[j]);
```

Comment: You are missing upper-case 'Ć' character.